# fscanf writing to string array wrong

Tags: c, scanf

I am reading a file word by word using fscanf and writing them to a char** array.

If I want to print the current index it works fine but after full writing finishes, printing the array causes wrong output.

```
char **stop_words = (char**)malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("englishstopwords.txt", "r");

int i = 0;
while(!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf(fp,"%s\n", &stop_words[i]);
    // printf("%s\n", &stop_words[i]); //this works fine
    i++;
}
// for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { //this works buggy
    // printf("%s\n", &stop_words[i]);
// }
fclose(fp);
```

Broken print looks like this:
immediatimportanimportanindex

working print look like this:
immediately
importance
important
index

What is the difference between them?

Comment: What is the magic number 850?

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `stop_words[i]`.

Comment: @Hakan Alp Also where are there the allocated pointers initialized char **stop_words = (char**)malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));?

Comment: I accidentally wrote, wrong outputs are starting from 5th index

Comment: And once you allocate the memory, `&stop_words[i]` should be just `stop_words[i]`. The array contains a pointer, you don't need the address of the pointer.

Comment: Initializing memory for stop_words[i] and getting stop_words[i] instead of its address solved my issue! thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

You did memory allocation fundamentally wrong.

`char **stop_words = (char**)malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));` only allocates a block of memory that is capable to store 1000 pointers.

The content of `stop_words[0]` to `stop_words[999]` is undefined, they are all garbage value after the `malloc()` returns.

Sometimes it looks fine to write to `stop_words[i]`, but it is just a lucky part that the garbage is a pointer to mapped memory (still bad though, you probably have a memory corruption because of that).

The fix for this is simply to allocate another block of memory to contain the data from your file.

---

#### Wrong target buffer

This part

```
fscanf(fp,"%s\n", &stop_words[i]);
```

writes to array of pointer that you have allocated with `malloc()`. The type of expression `&stop_words[i]` itself doesn't match with `%s`, you should really activate warn flags and a good compiler should warn you about that by default.

#### Potential buffer overflow

Your method to read a line is dangerous, because `fscanf` with `%s` doesn't care about how big your buffer is, and your program is vulnerable to buffer overflow because of that.

Fix for this is that you can use `fgets` and specify the size of your buffer.

You can then `realloc()` if a line has more than allocated memory for the buffer. To detect this, you can see the last character returned. If it is a line feed, then it is the end of line, otherwise it may be end of file or a line that has characters more than buffer size (so you can decide to realloc).

---

## Fix for this

---

### englishstopwords.txt (sample file for testing)

```
i
me
my
myself
we
our
test_long_line_123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123
ours
ourselves
```

---

### test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_WORDS   (1000u)
#define INIT_ALLOC  (128u)

int main(void)
{
    size_t i, total_words;
    FILE *fp;
    char **stop_words = malloc(MAX_WORDS * sizeof(*stop_words));
    /* TODO: Handle `stop_words == NULL` */

    fp = fopen("englishstopwords.txt", "r");
    /* TODO: Handle `fp == NULL` */


    i = 0;
    while (true) {
        size_t len = 0;
        char *ret, *buf = malloc(INIT_ALLOC * sizeof(*buf));
        /* TODO: Handle `buf == NULL` */

        ret = buf;
    re_fgets:
        ret = fgets(ret, INIT_ALLOC, fp);
        if (ret == NULL) {
            /* We've reached the end of file */

            if (len == 0) {
                /*
                 * Throw away the buffer, this is unused
                 */
                free(buf);
            } else {
                /* Last line buffer. */
                stop_words[i++] = buf;
            }

            break;
        }


        len = strlen(buf);
        if (buf[len - 1] != '\n') {
            /*
             *
             * We don't see an LF, this means this line
             * has more than `INIT_ALLOC` characters or
             * it may be the EOF.
             *
             */

            ret = realloc(buf, (len + 1 + INIT_ALLOC) * sizeof(*buf));
            /* TODO: Handle `ret == NULL` */


            buf = ret;
            /*
             * Shift the pointer to the right (end of string).
             * Because this line has not been fully read.
             *
             * We put the next `fgets` buffer to the end of this
             * string.
             */
            ret += len;
            goto re_fgets;
        }

        /* TODO: Trim CR on Windows platform */

        /* Trim the LF */
        buf[len - 1]  = '\0';
        stop_words[i++] = buf;

        if (i >= MAX_WORDS) {
            /*
             * TODO: You can do realloc(stop_words, ...) if you
             * want to.
             */
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    total_words = i;
    for (i = 0; i < total_words; i++)
        printf("%s\n", stop_words[i]);


    for (i = 0; i < total_words; i++)
        free(stop_words[i]);

    free(stop_words);
    return 0;
}
```

---

## Compile and Run

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ cat englishstopwords.txt 
i
me
my
myself
we
our
test_long_line_123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123
ours
ourselves
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.c -o test
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --track-fds=yes --error-exitcode=99 -s ./test
==503906== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==503906== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==503906== Using Valgrind-3.17.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==503906== Command: ./test
==503906== 
i
me
my
myself
we
our
test_long_line_123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123
ours
ourselves
==503906== 
==503906== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open (3 std) at exit.
==503906== 
==503906== HEAP SUMMARY:
==503906==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==503906==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 22 frees, 20,476 bytes allocated
==503906== 
==503906== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==503906== 
==503906== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$
```

Comment: Nice answer.     Consider allocating to the size of the referenced object, not type.  `stop_words = malloc(MAX_WORDS * sizeof(char *));` --> `stop_words = malloc(sizeof *stop_words * MAX_WORDS);`

Comment: Thanks! really great answer!